# Find closest next day from dates array, using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, momentjs

I have an array:

```
dates = [
"2019-10-04T12:38:02.506204+00:00",
"2019-10-04T14:59:39.370487+00:00",
"2019-10-04T14:59:50.897597+00:00",
"2019-10-04T14:59:57.344401+00:00",
"2019-10-04T15:00:04.631711+00:00",
"2019-10-04T15:00:13.460667+00:00",
"2019-10-04T15:00:21.672496+00:00",
"2019-10-04T15:00:29.643194+00:00",
"2019-10-04T15:00:37.022307+00:00",
"2019-10-04T15:01:00.134239+00:00",
"2019-10-04T15:01:08.146224+00:00",
"2019-10-04T15:01:15.205999+00:00",
"2019-10-04T15:01:21.877861+00:00",
"2019-10-04T15:01:28.089368+00:00",
"2019-10-04T16:29:05.438103+00:00",
"2019-10-04T16:29:49.927139+00:00",
"2019-10-05T16:35:00.994699+00:00",
"2019-10-06T08:45:47.289637+00:00",
"2019-10-06T08:46:11.294362+00:00",
"2019-10-06T08:46:23.702585+00:00",
"2019-10-06T08:46:33.374726+00:00",
"2019-10-06T08:46:42.726666+00:00",
"2019-10-06T08:46:52.916887+00:00",
"2019-10-06T08:47:02.659273+00:00",
"2019-10-06T16:08:14.975139+00:00",
"2019-10-06T16:08:29.047735+00:00",
"2019-10-06T16:08:42.831487+00:00",
"2019-10-06T16:08:58.472631+00:00",
"2019-10-07T08:32:43.248706+00:00",
"2019-10-07T08:37:00.512249+00:00",
"2019-10-07T08:38:12.188744+00:00",
"2019-10-07T08:40:08.362515+00:00",
"2019-10-07T08:41:57.151322+00:00",
"2019-10-07T08:46:52.107963+00:00",
"2019-10-07T08:53:38.604697+00:00",
"2019-10-07T08:53:53.449463+00:00",
"2019-10-07T09:15:31.659223+00:00"
]
```

I need to make a switch with two buttons, the first will switch the dates forward, the second - back.
Dates are used from an array.

Help with JS please.

Comment: How do you determine what "next day" means? Relative to today? Relative to another date?

Comment: @VLAZ i have "currentDate" var - min date from array.

Comment: So do you want the *next* date (`"2019-10-04T14:59:39.370487+00:00"`) or the next date that is on a new day (`"2019-10-05T16:35:00.994699+00:00"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`isBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) method on Moment.js objects. If you pass in the second argument as `"day"`, then it would consider that:

- `"2019-10-04T12:38:02.506204+00:00"` (4th of October) is before `"2019-10-05T16:35:00.994699+00:00"` (5th of October)
- `"2019-10-04T12:38:02.506204+00:00"` (4th of October) is **not** before `"2019-10-04T14:59:39.370487+00:00"` (4th of October)

```js
let dates = [
  "2019-10-04T12:38:02.506204+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T14:59:39.370487+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T14:59:50.897597+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T14:59:57.344401+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T15:00:04.631711+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T15:00:13.460667+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T15:00:21.672496+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T15:00:29.643194+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T15:00:37.022307+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T15:01:00.134239+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T15:01:08.146224+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T15:01:15.205999+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T15:01:21.877861+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T15:01:28.089368+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T16:29:05.438103+00:00",
  "2019-10-04T16:29:49.927139+00:00",
  "2019-10-05T16:35:00.994699+00:00",
  "2019-10-06T08:45:47.289637+00:00",
  "2019-10-06T08:46:11.294362+00:00",
  "2019-10-06T08:46:23.702585+00:00",
  "2019-10-06T08:46:33.374726+00:00",
  "2019-10-06T08:46:42.726666+00:00",
  "2019-10-06T08:46:52.916887+00:00",
  "2019-10-06T08:47:02.659273+00:00",
  "2019-10-06T16:08:14.975139+00:00",
  "2019-10-06T16:08:29.047735+00:00",
  "2019-10-06T16:08:42.831487+00:00",
  "2019-10-06T16:08:58.472631+00:00",
  "2019-10-07T08:32:43.248706+00:00",
  "2019-10-07T08:37:00.512249+00:00",
  "2019-10-07T08:38:12.188744+00:00",
  "2019-10-07T08:40:08.362515+00:00",
  "2019-10-07T08:41:57.151322+00:00",
  "2019-10-07T08:46:52.107963+00:00",
  "2019-10-07T08:53:38.604697+00:00",
  "2019-10-07T08:53:53.449463+00:00",
  "2019-10-07T09:15:31.659223+00:00"
]

let currentDate = moment(dates[0]); //pick a spot for the "current time"

//sort the dates to ensure they are sequential
dates.sort();

let nextDate = dates.
  filter(isoDate => currentDate.isBefore(isoDate, "day")) //filter anything before the current
   [0]; //take the first (lowest) date

console.log(nextDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```